# how to delete/remove wordpress feed urls in header?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to delete/remove `wordpress feed` urls from the `head` tag in `header.php`?

Example these URLs:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Example Business &raquo; Feed" href="http://example.com/feed/"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Example Business &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://example.com/comments/feed/"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Example Business &raquo; Home Page Live Comments Feed" href="http://example.com/home/feed/"/>
```

I don't want to use any plugin for the same.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I’ve recently had a need to remove the feed url link elements and in trying to avoid customising the core **WordPress** functions the following solutions works.

Ensure you have a `functions.php` file in your theme directory that you are using. If not create the file and edit the file. The following lines will help remove select lines from your `wp_head()` function:

```
<?php
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 ); // Display the links to the extra feeds such as category feeds
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 ); // Display the links to the general feeds: Post and Comment Feed
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' ); // Display the link to the Really Simple Discovery service endpoint, EditURI link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link' ); // Display the link to the Windows Live Writer manifest file.
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'index_rel_link' ); // index link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0 ); // prev link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0 ); // start link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link', 10, 0 ); // Display relational links for the posts adjacent to the current post.
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' ); // Display the XHTML generator that is generated on the wp_head hook, WP version
?>
```

Comment: This is a very clean solution. But note that if you don't use a selfmade theme or child theme these changes will be overwritten with the next theme update. To prevent this create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) or make a small plugin out of this.

Comment: To add to Gerald's comments, if you want to add this code to a child theme create a new function in the child theme's functions.php script called something like override_parent_actions() and then copy-and-paste Kailash's code into that function (minus the PHP tags, of course). Immediately after the new function, add the following code: add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'override_parent_actions' ); This will then remove the feed URLs without needing to modify the parent theme.

Comment: Thanks @NoelWhitemore Very good suggestion to overcome the child theme update.

Comment: @KailashYadav, why are pagination rel links included here? Aren't they helpful for SEO bots to discover more of your website content quicker?

Comment: @OksanaRomaniv Yes, these are useful, i just added all the links which can be managed using above method rest it all depends from project to project and business requirement.

Comment: I found the `remove_action()`s worked in my child theme php WITHOUT wrapping them in a function called by `add_action()`

Answer (score 7):

You can add this code in your WordPress theme/plugin. to remove all the unnecessary  tags from head including WordPress feed tags.

Github Gist URL: https://gist.github.com/coder618/29782921f79235f26285847916c2a122

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'prefix_remove_unnecessary_tags' );

function prefix_remove_unnecessary_tags(){

    // REMOVE WP EMOJI
    remove_action('wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7);
    remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles');

    remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
    remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );


    // remove all tags from header
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'index_rel_link' );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link' );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link', 10, 0 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head',      'rest_output_link_wp_head'              );
    remove_action( 'wp_head',      'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links'         );
    remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'rest_output_link_header', 11 );

    // language
    add_filter('multilingualpress.hreflang_type', '__return_false');
}
```

Comment: Attention: be aware that this code will remove a lot more than just the RSS references. Test before using!

Comment: Perfect for me!

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way, to remove RSS FEED button is more simple, just go in Appearance / Editor / and REMOVE :

```
 <div id="profiles" class="clearfix gutter-left">
                 <?php do_action( 'graphene_social_profiles' ); ?>
           </div>
```

from Theme Header (header.php) of your theme, for me Graphene. Others ways don't work for me, but this way is very simple !!!! Tested!!! PS: Find the same type of script changing graphene, word with the name of your theme.